# How can I add a new user account?

Tags: user

I cannot see how to add a new user account in Elementary OS, despite having reviewed the system settings and options.
Can anyone advise on the required steps please?

I already tried using the Guest account, but when logged in as Guest, the computer would not connect to the wifi network, plus I couldn't see how to permanently add Firefox to the Dock (since all changes are reversed, when logging out).

So, I need to create a new user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Go to system settings --> **user accounts** --> *unlock* --> Click on **+** (at left bottom corner).

Then add details.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just add user the [other](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3228/2708) procedure is enough.

If you need to add groups or add users to groups you can install the `gnome-system-tools`.

Install from software Center or with terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Open **users & groups** (gnome-system-tools)  --> **Add** --> add details.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]