# Can't add new user (System is installed, I am not in installation mode)

Tags: release-freya, settings, user

- I am not able to add user in System Settings /User Accounts
- I have tried installing the gnome-system-tools as suggested in the other
  post (linked in the end of this post)
- I am logged in with my default admin user account

I have unlocked the System Settings/User accounts locker

I can fill all fields out after clicking the + button

After finished no new account is visible in the list, nor on log in screen

[How can I add a new user account?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-account)

System information:
elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya 64-bit MacBook (installed)

Best Regards
M Edvardsen

Comment: Does your `Create User` button ever light up blue like this? http://i.imgur.com/bLFLj5T.png

Comment: Hi Lewis. Yes it does. I can create the account. But nothing seems to be created. Possibly in the "background" but not in the user list in gui and not on the login screen

Comment: tried terminal:---
 `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`  

the new user is not visible in the list either.  

Then tried: `sudo adduser username`
  
system says something close to this:  
---
`creates user "username"  
creates new group the_ same_ as_username (a number)  
creates new user "username" (a number) with group the_same_as_username    
useradd: existing lock file /etc/subuid.lock without a PID  
useradd: can not lock /etc/subuid; try again later.  
adduser: _"usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/_username_ -g _same as username_ -s /bin/bash -u _userid_ _username_" responded with error code 16. quits.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the OS. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
groups youruser
sudo useradd newuser -m -G x-group,y-group,z-group
```

Option -G assigns newuser to x, y and z groups, option -m creates the home of newuser

```
sudo passwd newuser
```

Comment: `groups youruser` generates a message: `groups: user youruser does not exist`

Comment: `sudo useradd youruser -m -g yourgroup` generates following error code: `useradd: existing lock file /etc/subuid.lock without a PID` `useradd: can't lock /etc/subuid; try again later`

Comment: I reinstalled elementary os freya. Now it is working.